# Turn quadratic minimization to quadratic maximization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

Is it possible to change quadratic minimization

$$J_{\text{min}} = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx + c^Tx$$
S.T
$$Ax \leq b$$
$$x \geq 0$$

To quadratic maximization by replacing $$c$$ to $b$ and $Q$ to $A$ just as in linear programming?

$$J_{\text{max}} = -\frac{1}{2}x^TQx + b^Tx$$
S.T
$$A^Tx \leq c$$
$$x \geq 0$$

Comment: Minimizing $f(x)$ is equivalent to maximizing $-f(x)$.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei Can you write an answer please about that.

Comment: There appears to be confusion between two very different things.  What you are talking about for Linear Programming is finding the (Lagrangian)  dual problem. The dual of a Quadratic Programming problem is more complicated than you hypothesize.  A very different, and theoretically much simpler concept is illustrated in the (1st) answer, which is that maximizing the negative of the objective function subject to the same constrains is equivalent (other than having to negate the value of the optimal objective) to minimizing the objective function subject to those same constraints.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone If you want to give a proof, then write an answer. Very intresting to see. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I'm writing a QP-solver in plain C code.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an off the shelf QP solver?  There are many, both for convex QP, as well as local and global optimization of non-convex QP.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I don't know. I just looked at Hildreth's QP solver and it seems to give a good result. Very fast too. Quadratic minimization works for Hildreth's QP-solver.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Here is the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896320322047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing $f(x)$ is equivalent to maximizing $−f(x)$, so
$$
\frac{1}{2} x^T Q x + c^T x\to \min \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \begin{cases}
Ax \leq b \\ x\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
is the same as
$$
-\frac{1}{2} x^T Q x - c^T x = \frac{1}{2} x^T (-Q) x + (-c^T) x\to \max \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \begin{cases}
Ax \leq b \\ x\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Wow that's easy! But it's not the same for linear programming =) Thank you

Comment: By the way! If I turn $Q$ and $c$ negative. I cannot solve the maximization problem.